# error in connect to sqlserver in windows and sql authentication mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, c#-4.0

i have a snippet that it work properly when i use windowsmode with follow connection string

```
data source=.;database=xDB;integrated security=true;
```

but i have to change it for sql and windows mode i changeit to

```
Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=xDB;User Id=krs;Password=12345;
```

but follow error occur

> Login failed for user 'krs'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

and when change dot(.) to(local) another error occur

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

plz help me im beginer  n confused.thank

Comment: Can you Please show here your full Connection String from Web.Config File and have you also tried to log in Sql Server with Same Credential that you are passing here?

Comment: To address the secondary issue - it's `localhost`, not `local`

Comment: Did you add this user to your access database?

Comment: i dont puit inweb config:            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=local;Initial Catalog=xdb;User Id=krs;Password=1234;");

Comment: yes imake login and user with krs name in sqlserver

Comment: i change it to locahost and  i get this error again:Login failed for user 'krs'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable the Named Pipe & TCP/IP in SQL Server configuration. Go through following link to enable that

http://www.triostechs.com/Microsoft-SQL-Server-2008/Microsoft-SQL-Server-2008-Enable-TCP/IP-or-Named-Pipes.html

Also Make sure, only one instance of the SQL Server running. If it is more than one, just verify which one you are connecting to.